# radio buttons incorrectly written to the database in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've a registration form, where user must chose one of 2 options.

Django renders all correctly, django admin also have it ok, but db records all possible choices as value.

forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email','password1','password2']

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    terms_compliance = forms.BooleanField(label=mark_safe('I agree with <a href="/questions/whyname/" target="_blank">terms and conditions </a>'))
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        widgets = {'role': forms.RadioSelect}
        fields = ('role','terms_compliance')
        def __init__(self):
            self.fields['terms_compliance'].initial  = True
```

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    role_choices = [('publisher','Publisher'), ('advertiser','Advertiser')]
    role = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=role_choices, default=None)
    terms_compliance = models.BooleanField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

In new instance (which is `user.userprofile.role_choices`) I need `advertiser` or `publisher`, but all I have is: `[('publisher','Publisher'), ('advertiser','Advertiser')]`

Comment: Can you show *how* you use the above form?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide choices in a Database Field. Do like this:

```py
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    class RoleChoice(ChoiceEnum):
        PUBLISHER = 'Издатель'
        ADVERTISER = 'Рекламодатель'

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=RoleChoice.choices(), default=None)
    terms_compliance = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

In Views.py, populate the DB like this.

For example:

```
...
choice = request.query_params.get('choice') or UserProfile.RoleChoice.PUBLISHER.value
...
```

For more details read from here: https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/enum_field.html